# Can we use elsa workflow for developing Windows Application?

Tags: asp.net, .net, .net-core, workflow, elsa-workflows

[elsa-workflows] I am developing a windows application with .Net framework without any Web APIs. This will be a long running workflow. Can I use Elsa workflow for Windows Application?

Did some research on Elsa and found out that it can be used for short console applications and long running Asp.Net Web applications. Not sure about whether we can use it for Windows Applications.

Comment: You can use Elsa with any .net application, but do you have any specific use case in mind?